# Prevent default issue in React component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a pretty basic React component. I'm trying to create a form that submits. When the form submits, I'm trying to prevent the default for submission behavior, as one does in React.

Here is the entire component (there's redux in here, but it shouldn't matter for this question):

```
import React from "react"; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

export class App extends React.Component {

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.dispatch(); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header role="banner">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <p>{this.props.data}</p>
                </header>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}></form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.data
}); 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

When I run my tests, I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Ignore the empty dispatch. I need this to pass first. What's going on here? Any thoughts?

Here is full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

   5 |     
   6 |     handleSubmit(event) {
>  7 |         event.preventDefault();
   8 |         this.props.dispatch(); 
   9 |     }
  10 |
```

Here is the test:

```
it('dispatches an action when form is submitted', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn(); 
    const wrapper = shallow(<App dispatch={spy} />); 
    const form = wrapper.find('form'); 
    form.simulate('submit'); 
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

Comment: Your prod code looks fine. Here's a sandbox that tests it: https://codesandbox.io/s/ypzj9nmzvx?expanddevtools=1

Instead, I think you have a test issue. Can you post your test code?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enzyme's `simulate` doesn't mock the event object, but you can pass one yourself (see [the docs for `simulate`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#simulateevent-args--self)), e.g.:

```
const mockEvent = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
form.simulate('submit', mockEvent);
```

Comment: That is weird. I've never run into this issue before with Enzyme. Anyway, this worked. Thanks!